# Pride is not the opposite of shame but its source. True humility is the only antidote to shame

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Wise words, but what exactly is [going on in the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89rKnkNDKdM)?

> Zuko  Why can't I do it? Instead of lightning it keeps exploding in my
> face ... like everything always does.
>
> Iroh  I was afraid this might happen. You will not be able to master
> lightning until you have dealt with the turmoil inside you.
>
> Zuko  What turmoil?
>
> Iroh  Zuko, you must let go of your feelings of shame if you want your
> anger to go away.
>
> Zuko  But I don't feel any shame at all. I'm as proud as ever.
>
> Iroh  Prince Zuko, pride is not the opposite of shame, but its source.
> True humility is the only antidote to shame.

Some guide questions for the main question:

1. What exactly was Zuko 'proud' of/about?
2. Why exactly was Zuko's pride causing Zuko to feel shame?
3. What does humility look like for Zuko here then? I mean, what should Zuko do / not do / think / not think to be humble?
4. Why would doing / not doing / thinking / not thinking that be an antidote for Zuko's shame?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to a question like this is inherently opinion-based. We have to dive a little into the themes of the show and character motifs. I'll reference plot points as often as I can think of them.

Iroh is saying that shame and pride are 2 sides of the same coin. Pride is when we're happy about our achievements. Shame is when we are not. Both are connected to our opinions of ourselves. To be humble is to let go of this mindset.

1. Zuko places a lot of importance on his royal blood. He believes he is "above" others, is capable of more, and bears that burden. On top of that, he is of the Fire Nation. This is the source of his pride.
2. He has failed to catch the Avatar. Over and over. His younger sister constantly surpasses him. Now he can't manifest lightning. In his own eyes, he's an abysmal failure.
3. Zuko needs to "let it go". The shame we carry holds us back. He can't focus, the life-force of Fire is bound up in knots inside of him. This mostly just ties in with the trope mentioned in 4.
4. This is a bit of a trope. [Enlightenment Superpowers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnlightenmentSuperpowers) (tv tropes). In fact, the main caption on the page is from the spinoff, *The Legend of Korra.*